How to put a variable/recordId in anchor tag <a href="somelink"+{acc.id} >"
I have a anchor tag where I am using a link inside href Attribute but I want to append a recordId with the link.
HTML:
<template>
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">

            <tbody>
                <template for:each={accList.data} for:item="acc">
                  <lightning-layout multiple-rows key={acc.id}>
                   <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="12" small-device-size="12"
                                      medium-device-size="12" large-device-size="12">
                    
                    <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-max-medium-table_stacked container">
                       <span class="logo slds-m-right_small"> 
                        <img src={acc.Logo__c} alt={altText} /></span>
                       
                  
                    <span> <b> {acc.Name}</b></span></br></br>

                    <span class="slds-p-left_large"></span>
                     <span class="logo slds-m-right_small cnt">Country Served:</span></br>
                   
                       <div class="country lineClamp" onclick={handleClick}><b> {acc.Country_or_Countries_Served__c}</b></div></br>


                        accountId = {acc.Id}
                        <a class="slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-m-right_small btn" href="i-need-a-broker/?BrokerId=accountId">Contact Broker</a>
                        <a class="slds-button slds-button_destructive" href="broker-info/?varAccountId=accountId">View Details</a>

                        </br></br>
                           </div>
</lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>
                </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</template>

JS:
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getBrokerAccountDeatils from '@salesforce/apex/BrokerAccountDetailsCtrl.getBrokerAccountDeatils';
export default class Broker_Landing_Page extends LightningElement {
    accList
    @wire(getBrokerAccountDeatils)
    accList;
}

i-need-a-broker?BrokerId= this is url when clicking on the button
but i need something like i-need-a-broker?BrokerId=123456789734456

LWC doesn't allow such expression in the template, so if the first part of the link is static and acc is an instance variable, you could have a getter in your JS class returning the whole url:
JS:
get brokerURL() {
    return `i-need-a-broker/?BrokerId=${this.acc.Id}`;
}

HTML:
<a class="slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-m-right_small btn" href={brokerURL}>Contact Broker</a>

EDIT
Since that anchor is added to the DOM inside a loop, you need to modify your elements adding a new property that holds the URL.
Keep in mind that if the list is provisioned by a wire adapter, it's immutable, so you need to clone each element in order to add the new property.
By the way, you declared accList two times, I'm going to decorate a function, not a property, with @wire and let accList holds the modified elements.
I'm goint to use Array.map() to create a new array populated with the modified element and I'll clone them using the destructuring assignment syntax (...)
JS:
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import getBrokerAccountDeatils from '@salesforce/apex/BrokerAccountDetailsCtrl.getBrokerAccountDeatils';

export default class Broker_Landing_Page extends LightningElement {
    accList

    @wire(getBrokerAccountDeatils)
    fetchBrokerAccountDeatils({ data, error}) {
        if (data) {
            this.accList = data.map((acc) => {
                return {
                    ...acc,
                    contactBrokerURL: `i-need-a-broker/?BrokerId=${acc.Id}`,
                    brokerInfoURL: `broker-info/?varAccountId=${acc.Id}`
                };
            });
        } else if (error) {
            // handle errors
        }
    }
}

Now in the HTML you could loop over accList, not accList.data and use both contactBrokerURL and brokerInfoURL properties:
<template>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered">

        <tbody>
            <template for:each={accList} for:item="acc">
                <lightning-layout multiple-rows key={acc.id}>
                    <lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto" padding="around-small" size="12">
                        <div class="slds-box slds-box_x-small slds-max-medium-table_stacked container">
                            <span class="logo slds-m-right_small"> 
                                <img src={acc.Logo__c} alt={altText} />
                            </span>

                            <span><b>{acc.Name}</b></span>
                            </br></br>

                            <span class="slds-p-left_large"></span>
                            <span class="logo slds-m-right_small cnt">Country Served:</span>
                            </br>

                            <div class="country lineClamp" onclick={handleClick}><b>{acc.Country_or_Countries_Served__c}</b></div>
                            </br>

                            <a class="slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-m-right_small btn" href={acc.contactBrokerURL}>Contact Broker</a>
                            <a class="slds-button slds-button_destructive" href={acc.brokerInfoURL}>View Details</a>
                            </br></br>
                        </div>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </lightning-layout>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

If you need a relative URL, please remember that it must start with a forward slash (/)

import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getBrokerAccountDeatils from '@salesforce/apex/BrokerAccountDetailsCtrl.getBrokerAccountDeatils';
export default class Broker_Landing_Page extends LightningElement {
accList
@wire(getBrokerAccountDeatils)
accList;
}             This is the JS file and in HTML I am using            <template for:each{accList.data}for:item="acc">
 . I have tried your both solution but on ui data are not showing. Please correct me where I am making the mistake. Thanks

@BabaiMukherjee I updated the answer, please check it again
